# pass user request in form action route in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, forms, routes, laravel-8

here is my simple form

```
<form id="test-form" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
        <div class="popup_box ">
            <div class="popup_inner">
                <h3>Make an Appointment</h3>
                <form action="{{route('doctorwithdatepopup',['date'=>$date,'id'=>$doctorsid])}}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                            <input id="datepicker" placeholder="Pick date" name="date">
                        </div>
                        @php
                            $Department = DB::table('departments')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
                        @endphp
                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                            <select class="form-select wide" id="departmentid" name="departmentid">
                                <option data-display="Select Department">Department</option>

                                @foreach ($Department as $item)
                                <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                              
                                
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-12">
                            <select class="form-select wide" id="doctorsid" name="doctorsid" class="">
                               
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <br>    
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-xl-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="boxed-btn3">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

inaction `['date'=>$date,'id'=>$doctorsid]` these two data I want pass based on user selection how can I do that?

for example

```
$date = $request->date
```

this one can handle in the controller but in action URL how can I pass user enter values ?

Comment: Where are you getting the variable $date and $doctorsid from?

Comment: in side of form there 2 select option

Comment: You can solve this by removing url parameters and using the request directly by taking all actions in you controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little tricky. Try to make 2 routes for that, first route to get user form requests. Second, your "doctorwithdatepopup" routes.

**web.php**

```
Route::post('url', [YourController::class, 'store'])->name('storeform');
Route::get('url2/{date}/{id}', [YourController::class, 'show'])->name('doctorwithdatepopup');
```

**YourController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // Some Validation, Logic, etc
    return redirect()->route('doctorwithdatepopup', ['date' => $request->date, 'id' => $doctorId]);
}

public function show($date, $id)
{
    return view('your view', compact('date', 'id'));
}
```